# Замена чисел по порядку

Tags: текст, числа, замена

Нужно заменить все 111 на числа по порядку. Как это реализовать? В идеале отчет числа задавать, например от 3000. Спасибо.

[image: До]

[image: После]

Примерно такой исходный код:

```
<item id="111">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="111">фото1</image>
<image id="111">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
<item id="111">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="111">фото1</image>
<image id="111">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
<item id="111">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="111">фото1</image>
<image id="111">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
```

Comment: Укажите хотя бы язык программирования или тип утилит, которыми нужно делать эти преобразования. Вариантов тьма.

Comment: На чем это реализовать, не знаю. Может notepad++, excel, php, онлайн сервис какой-нибудь. Главное что-бы работало и мог запустить это далекий от программирования человек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, с учетом неопределенности, проще сделать на том, что будет работать везде – [html](/questions/tagged/html) + [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Попробовать онлайн можно тут ([репозиторий](https://github.com/gil9red/static_site_for_id_replace)): https://gil9red.github.io/static_site_for_id_replace/

У меня немного опыта в нем, поэтому получилось на коленке:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script>
            function run() {
                var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
                var counter = 3000;

                while (text.includes('id="111"')) {
                    text = text.replace('id="111"', 'id="' + counter + '"');
                    counter++;
                }
                
                document.getElementById("output").value = text;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="input" cols="50" rows="20">
<item id="111">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="111">фото1</image>
<image id="111">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
<item id="111">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="111">фото1</image>
<image id="111">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
<item id="111">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="111">фото1</image>
<image id="111">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
                    </textarea>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="output" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><button onclick="run()">Выполнить!</button><td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**P.S.** достаточно код сохранить в файл формате `.html` и передавать кому понадобится. А клиенту нужно будет открыть его через браузер, вставить/ввести данные и кликнуть на кнопку

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что нужно, лучше не придумаешь!

Comment: @АнтонКорф Если вам ответ понравился, отметьте его как решение :)

Comment: Нажал на галочку, наверно это означает пометить как решение?

Comment: @АнтонКорф, да, так и есть

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм на [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) через регулярное выражение:

```
import re

text = """\
<item id="111">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="111">фото1</image>
<image id="111">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
<item id="111">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="111">фото1</image>
<image id="111">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
<item id="111">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="111">фото1</image>
<image id="111">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
"""

counter = 3000 - 1

def on_sub(_):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return f'id="{counter}"'

new_text = re.sub(r'id="\d+"', on_sub, text)
print(new_text)
```

Текст в `new_text`:

```xml
<item id="3000">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="3001">фото1</image>
<image id="3002">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
<item id="3003">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="3004">фото1</image>
<image id="3005">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
<item id="3006">
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>Описание</description>
<images>
<image id="3007">фото1</image>
<image id="3008">фото2</image>
</images>
</item>
```

---

**PS.** python интерпретируемый, поэтому ему понадобится что-то через что его можно будет запустить, а значит понадобится установка интерпретатора.

Чтобы клиенту отдавать, можно:

- Собрать исполняемый файл, например используя: [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller), [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) и т.п.
- Отдавать вместе с интерпретатором питона (`python.exe`). Т.е. будет папка с интерпретатором и скриптами программы. И будет использоваться cmd/bash скрипт для запуска, типо: `python.exe main.py`
- Если используется Unix-подобная система, то в ней уже будет питон, поэтому можно просто запускать скрипт.

Другой вариант, это сделать веб-сервер, который и будет обрабатывать текст клиента, на питоне это проще всего через [flask](/questions/tagged/flask) или [bottle](/questions/tagged/bottle) сделать.

Еще, если делать десктопную утилиту, нужно определиться она будет консольная или графическая. Если графическая, то нужно определиться через какую библиотеку будет создаваться интерфейс: tkinter (он по умолчанию входит в библиотеку питона), Qt, GTK и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо за решение. К сожалению, довольно не просто в исполнении. Нашел плагин питона для notepad++, но в нем не хочет работать.